# ¿Cómo imprimo secuencias de escape?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$buf = "";
$buf .= "class validate\n";
$buf .= "{\n";
$buf .= "\tpublic function isstring(\$string)\n";
$buf .= "\t{\n";
$buf .= "\t\treturn (is_string(\$string));\n";
$buf .= "\t}\n\n";
$buf .= "\tpublic function isint(\$int)\n";
$buf .= "\t{\n";
$buf .= "\t\treturn (preg_match(\"/^([0-9.,-]+)$/\", \$int) > 0);\n";
$buf .= "\t}\n\n";
$buf .= "\tpublic function isbool(\$bool)\n";
$buf .= "\t{\n";
$buf .= "\t\t\$b = 1 * \$bool;\n";
$buf .= "\t\treturn (\$b == 1 || \$b == 0);\n";
$buf .= "\t}\n";
$buf .= "}\n\n";
echo $buf;
```

pero me imprime así:

```
class validate { public function isstring($string) { return (is_string($string)); } public function isint($int) { return (preg_match("/^([0-9.,-]+)$/", $int) > 0); } public function isbool($bool) { $b = 1 * $bool; return ($b == 1 || $b == 0); } }
```

cuando abro el código fuente si se ve ordenado:

```
class validate
{
    public function isstring($string)
    {
        return (is_string($string));
    }

    public function isint($int)
    {
        return (preg_match("/^([0-9.,-]+)$/", $int) > 0);
    }

    public function isbool($bool)
    {
        $b = 1 * $bool;
        return ($b == 1 || $b == 0);
    }
}
```

¿cómo puedo hacer para que me imprima los caracteres especiales?

Comment: probaste cambiar los \n por <br>?

Comment: @jorgemarquez, esta creando código javascript, colocar `<br>` produciría error.

Comment: @Alf depende de donde lo mires, si utilizas el inspector del navegador, este lo ordena adecuadamente para su facil lectura, si lo habres con clic derecho y ver código fuente, puede que te salga de la manera que estas diciendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método reservado de PHP [highlight_string](http://php.net/manual/es/function.highlight-string.php)  de esta manera:

```
$buff = <<<PHP
class validate
{
   public function isstring($string)
   {
       return (is_string($string));
   }

   public function isint($int)
   {
       return (preg_match("/^([0-9.,-]+)$/", $int) > 0);
   }

   public function isbool($bool)
   {
       $b = 1 * $bool;
       return ($b == 1 || $b == 0);
   }
}
PHP;
highlight_string($buff);
```

Suerte.

Comment: El `echo` es redundante. La propia función da salida de la cadena que le pasas como argumento. +1.

Comment: Gracias @OscarR no ví el despiste

Comment: me funciono! muchas gracias!